# how to change a vertical css menu to be horizontal

Tags: html, css

im using this css for my vertical menu:

```
.vertical-nav{
    width:200px;
    height:auto;
    list-style:none;
    float:left;
    margin-right:40px;
}
.vertical-nav li{
    width:200px;
    height:25px;
    margin:5px;
    padding:5px;
    background-color:#666666;
    border:none;
    text-align:center;
    float:left;
}
.vertical-nav li:hover{
    background-color:#f36f25;
    color:#FFFFFF;
}
.vertical-nav li a{
    font-family:Calibri, Arial;
    font-size:18px;
    font-weight:bold;
    color:#ffffff;
    text-decoration:none;
}
.vertical-nav li.current {
    background-color:#F36F25;
}
.vertical-nav li.current a {
    color:#FFFFFF;
}
```

and here is my html:

```
<ul class="vertical-nav">
<li><a href="index.php">Home</a></li>
<li><a href="staff.php">Staff</a></li>
<li><a href="invoices.php">Invoices</a></li>
<li><a href="tickets.php">Tickets</a></li>
<li><a href="openticket.php">Open Ticket</a></li>
</ul>
```

what would be the best way to make the links display horizontal?

Comment: Assign 'float: left' or 'display: inline-block' to the list items.

Comment: @Blazemonger: OP already has floats, the only thing restricting the li:s is the width of the nav.

Comment: There is a classical example of horizontal navigation bar utilizing list properties published on w3schools: http://www.w3schools.com/css/css_navbar.asp

Answer (score 0):

If you change the width of the .vertical-nav to for example 100%, the li:s will float horizontally. The width of the nav have to be enough to make room for all of them, otherwise they will line up under each other.

Answer (score 0):

I removed `width:200px;` & `float:left` from `.vertical-nav` and changed `float:left;` to `display:inline-block;` on `.vertical-nav li`

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/MaqBE/)

```
.vertical-nav{
    height:auto;
    list-style:none;
    margin-right:40px;
}
.vertical-nav li{
    width:200px;
    height:25px;
    margin:5px;
    padding:5px;
    background-color:#666666;
    border:none;
    text-align:center;
    display:inline-block;
}
.vertical-nav li:hover{
    background-color:#f36f25;
    color:#FFFFFF;
}
.vertical-nav li a{
    font-family:Calibri, Arial;
    font-size:18px;
    font-weight:bold;
    color:#ffffff;
    text-decoration:none;
}
.vertical-nav li.current {
    background-color:#F36F25;
}
.vertical-nav li.current a {
    color:#FFFFFF;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

try to change the width of `.vertical-nav`

```
.vertical-nav{
    height:auto;
    list-style:none;
    float:left;
    padding:0;
    width:1100px;
}
```

working [demo](http://jsfiddle.net/6J8SU/2/)

Answer (score 0):

add this to li

```
.vertical-nav li{
    ...
    display:inline;
    /*or */
    display:inline-block;
    ...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

What you have written is correct. You just need to change the first css to include ul:

```
.vertical-nav ul {

rather than:

.vertical-nav {

And it's done :)
```

Answer (score 0):

you chould not set the same width of container and li try to set container width auto

```
      .vertical-nav{

       width:auto;
       list-style:none;
       margin-right:40px;
       }
```